# Can I leave Schengen one day after my visa expires?

Tags: visas, schengen, overstaying, hungary

I have a Schengen visa from 14th to 17th. Due to some circumstances, I had to change the flight from 17th to 18th, so I'm not flying out of Schengen on 18th around noon. Is this legal? If not, what are my options to extend my visa?

Comment: No it’s not legal, if you stay longer than your allowed number of days you’ll effectively be overstaying and might be subject to a fine or even a ban on future Schengen visas. Extensions are typically only possible in extenuating circumstances, you don’t state why your plans changed but unless it was eg an emergency it’s unlikely you’d get an extension.

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with Schengen visas, check the validity period and duration of stay on your visa. Often the Schengen states grant a few more days validity than duration so that the traveler can shift the *entire* trip a bit, arriving one day later and departing one day later. They may have given you more validity than you applied for. But that only works if both validity and duration are left.

Comment: @Traveller Not "effectively overstaying" but literally overstaying. This is _precisely_ what the word means: staying longer than your visa allows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, a visa valid until the 17th means that you have to leave before midnight that day.

- If the reasons why you have to re-schedule are totally out of your control, you might be able to get an extension on humanitarian grounds. Examples might be an airport that closes down due to bad weather, or you or a close relative being in hospital with an illness that prevents travel. Contact the immigration authorities **now**, before the visa expires.
- Other reasons like saving a lot of money by flying later are not acceptable.
- If you were to get a new Schengen visa valid from the 18th, you would not have to leave between the midnight of the 17th and the morning of the 18th. But that will be difficult if the 17th is the 17th September.

Overstaying may result in a fine, and it will make future Schengen visa much more difficult.

Comment: what if its a business reason for staying longer? Will result in a fine?

Comment: and is there a way for me to arrive to the airport on 17th at midnight and wait until my flight on the next day?

Comment: @nikolaevra, I don't know about the fine. The practice varies between Schengen countries. But the problems with the next visa **will** happen. Business is no acceptable reason to overstay.

Comment: @nikolaevra, re the airport, that depends on the airport. Some smaller ones close overnight. Others might not allow you into the departure area until a certain time before your flight leaves.